# Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object using Vue3 and Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I get a Vue warning: Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with markRaw or using shallowRef instead of ref. But nowhere I'm using `ref` nor `shallowRef` or `markRaw`.

Code:

```html
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <ion-nav :root="MorePageContainer"></ion-nav>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonNav, IonPage } from '@ionic/vue';
import MorePageComponent from "@/components/MorePageComponent.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        IonNav, IonPage
    },

    data() {
        return {
            MorePageComponent
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Why do I get this warning? I am not using `ref`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: move the component from `data` to `setup` like so:

```js
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <ion-nav :root="MorePageContainer"></ion-nav>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonNav, IonPage } from '@ionic/vue';
import MorePageComponentfrom "@/components/MorePageComponent.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        IonNav, IonPage
    },

    setup() {
        return {
            MorePageComponent
        }
    }
}
</script>
```